# Using text-boxes and buttons in android

Tags: java, android

This is my first app and I am having problem. It crashes very time I click the button. Idea of the app is to do a simple calculation with three numbers from the three textboxes and output the result into another textbox. here is my code.

```
package com.example.jeehbs.myfirstapp;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void mathIt(View view){
    EditText price = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.price);
    EditText oz = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.oz);
    EditText amount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amount);
    int p = Integer.parseInt(price.getText().toString());
    int o = Integer.parseInt(oz.getText().toString());
    int a = Integer.parseInt(amount.getText().toString());
    int result = (a*o)/p;
    TextView resultView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultView);
    resultView.setText(result);
}
}
```

Comment: Could be any one of a number of exceptions. You need to post logcat

Comment: Where is your click handler for the button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setText` takes a string parameter not an integer try `resultView.setText(String.valueOf(result));`. The integer parameter is a reference for a string resource `R.string.string_name`

Answer (score 0):

You said you were putting the result in a textbox, but you casting it to a TextView:

```
TextView resultView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultView);
```

Try using EditText here instead?